# SQL server query to find values containing only special chars?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, special-characters

I need to write a query to pull values from a column containing ***only*** special characters. I know that the below query would give me all values containing at least one special char but that is not what I need. Can anybody help me please?

```
SAMPLE DATA -

    ORG
    ^^567
    ~423
    %^&/
    329
```

I need to write a query which will return only  `%^&/` from the above sample data.

```
SELECT org
FROM table_A
WHERE org like '%[^a-Z0-9]%'
```

Comment: `NOT LIKE '%[a-Z0-9]%'`?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data along with the expected output? A SQLFiddle for this would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT org
FROM table_A
WHERE org Not like '%[a-Z0-9]%'
```

**Demo**

```
SELECT org
FROM   (SELECT '1asdasdf' org
        UNION
        SELECT '$asd#'
        UNION
        SELECT '$^%$%') a
WHERE  org Not Like '%[a-Z0-9]%'
```

**Result:** $^%$%

Comment: This provides me values which are NOT having special characters. I need values having ONLY special chars.

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi - Did you atleast execute my query. It will bring rows which has only special characters

Comment: I think you just now edited it. Let me try to run it.

Comment: It was edited to add an example, the query is still the same (as it's the same that I also posted as a comment for you to try)